# VectorDrawableCompat draws icon with displacement

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

Please, explain me how to fix it? I load vector drawable calling `VectorDrawableCompat.create(context.getResources(), resId, context.getTheme());`

It works on all supported devices (starting from API 8) but draws all icon with displacement. Why? I cannot understand. Just for example, it's `NavigationView` menu:

[image: Screenshot]

Layout boundaries:

[image: Screenshot when boundary showing enabled]

**`build.gradle`**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
}
```

**Example of `VectorDrawable`**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M19,3h-1L18,1h-2v2L8,3L8,1L6,1v2L5,3c-1.11,0 -1.99,0.9 -1.99,2L3,19c0,1.1 0.89,2 2,2h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2L21,5c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zM19,19L5,19L5,8h14v11zM7,10h5v5L7,15z"/>
</vector>
```

P.S. I made this screenshot on Android 6.0 emulator with software render (Ubuntu 16.04 and radeon HD 5xxx, Imma lucky). Unfortunately, I haven't a real device so... May it be due to the software render?

Comment: 1) In your emulator go to Settings > Developer options > Drawing > Show layout bounds. Turn that on and post another screenshot. 2) What version of support libs are you using? Or post build.gradle file. 3) Can you post more ode around `VectorDrawableCompat.create`?

Comment: how are you attaching that drawable to your view?  View.setBackground? or as a compound drawable?

Comment: As `setIcon()` for menu item

Comment: post your <vector> then

Comment: It's built-in vector assets! Vector is correct) I know android vector format) It's a lite SVG with small Android wrapper

Comment: I already almost sure that problem in emulator only. Tomorrow I will test it on the real device.

Comment: so post it. is it a long asset or what?

Comment: Android Studio has built-in vector asset generator. I use it. It isn't app assets files, just vector drawable was generated by Android Studio.

Comment: ok i know how studio generates them, so how does it look like?

Comment: k, I posted `VectorDrawable` sample.

Comment: run [this](http://pastebin.com/V0p5spgA) and watch the logcat, the funny thing is that on 4.4 and 5.0 both items use `android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat` and it works well but on 6.0 only std `VectorDrawable` works ;-(

Comment: and even more funny thing is that if you wrap your `VectorDrawableCompat` around another `Drawable` let it be LayerDrawable, InsetDrawable or support.v7.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper it starts automagically work

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it as soon as will have access to my computer

Comment: Problem was in the software render. I tested app on the real device. But all same thank you for help!